# Game objects move left and up, but don't move right and down

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

UPDATE

I see, providing code partly doesn't decide the problem. There are a lot of files, so I'll provide all aplication via GitHub for anybody would like to try to decide this problem:

https://github.com/johnydominus/CrimsonLikeGameSMFL

---

Sorry in advance for my English and programming knowledge. I'm newbie.
I'm making a 2D game using C++ and SFML SDK. The game is similar to CrimsonLand (2003): player should be walking on map and shooting monsters, while they trying to reach him.
For the moment player is walking and monsters are chasing him, but only if their direction is left or up. If needed direction is right or down - they don't move. Monsters just staying and staring at players direction. And player just doesn't move when right or down buttons pressed.

I've implement 2 movement coordinates systems - relative to map (to handle game events, like intersection monsters with bullets) and relative to player (to center "camera" on player). Movement written to map coordinates first, then it is transformed to player relative coordinates. Hence, drawing is using player relative coordinates. However, it doesn't look like that problem is in drawing.

Input is working - I've tried to change movement assignment (just for check) and set to move left when right button pressed and up when down button pressed - and it worked: player moved up both by up and down buttons and moved left by left and right buttons.

I'll try to delete all strings, that don't relate to the problem. But due to fact, that I don't have a clear idea what is wrong - there will be quite a lot of code.
Map, monster and player headers, and .cpp files - declaration and definition of game objects. 
Engine header and .cpp - declaration and definition of engine, that handles objects interaction.
Input and update .cpp's - definition of Engine methods, that handle respectively input from keyboard and updating objects position and state.

## player.h

```
class Player :
    public Object
{
private:
    std::vector<float> mapSize{0,0};
    int speed = 1;

    POINT prevPosition;
    std::vector<float> relatMovement{ 0,0 };

    bool leftPressed;
    bool rightPressed;
    bool upPressed;
    bool downPressed;

public:
    POINT Position;
    POINT relatPosition;

    void moveLeft();
    void moveRight();
    void moveUp();
    void moveDown();
    void stopLeft();
    void stopRight();
    void stopUp();
    void stopDown();

    void update(float elapsedTime);
};
```

## player.cpp

```
void Player::moveLeft()
{
    leftPressed = true;
}

void Player::moveRight()
{
    rightPressed = true;
}

void Player::moveUp()
{
    upPressed = true;
}

void Player::moveDown()
{
    downPressed = true;
}

void Player::stopLeft()
{
    leftPressed = false;
}

void Player::stopRight()
{
    rightPressed = false;
}

void Player::stopUp()
{
    upPressed = false;
}

void Player::stopDown()
{
    downPressed = false;
}

void Player::update(float elapsedTime)
{
    if (rightPressed) 
        Position.x += speed * elapsedTime;

    if (leftPressed)
        Position.x -= speed * elapsedTime;

    if (upPressed) 
        Position.y -= speed * elapsedTime;

    if (downPressed) 
        Position.y += speed * elapsedTime;

    relatMovement[0] = Position.x - prevPosition.x;
    relatMovement[1] = Position.y - prevPosition.y;

    prevPosition = Position;
}
```

## monster.h

```
class Monster :
public Object
{
private:
float pathLength;
Player* thePlayer;
Map* theMap;
POINT playerPosition;
POINT playerRelatPosition;
POINT nextStep;
std::vector<float> playerRelatMovement{0,0};
std::vector<float> direction{ 0,0 };
std::vector<float> vSpeed{ 0,0 };

public:
POINT Position;
POINT relatPosition;

POINT checkUpdate(float elapsedTime);
void update(float elapsedTime, POINT position);
};
```

## monster.cpp

```
POINT Monster::checkUpdate(float elapsedTime)
{
nextStep = Position;
playerPosition = *(thePlayer->getPosition());

direction[0] = playerPosition.x - Position.x;
direction[1] = playerPosition.y - Position.y;

pathLength = sqrt(pow(direction[0], 2) + pow(direction[1], 2));

direction[0] /= pathLength;
direction[1] /= pathLength;

vSpeed[0] = ((float)direction[0] * (float)speed)/10.0;
vSpeed[1] = ((float)direction[1] * (float)speed)/10.0;

nextStep.x += vSpeed[0];
nextStep.y += vSpeed[1];

return nextStep;
}

void Monster::update(float elapsedTime, POINT aNextStep)
{
Position = aNextStep;
playerPosition = *(thePlayer->getPosition());
playerRelatPosition = *(thePlayer->getRelatPosition());

relatPosition.x = playerRelatPosition.x + (Position.x - playerPosition.x);
relatPosition.y = playerRelatPosition.y + (Position.y - playerPosition.y);

shape.left = Position.x - (size[0] / 2);
shape.right = Position.x + (size[0] / 2);
shape.top = Position.y - (size[1] / 2);
shape.bottom = Position.y + (size[1] / 2);
```

}

## map.h

```
class Map:
public Object
{
private:
std::vector<float> relatMovement{0,0};
std::vector<float> size{0,0};
Player* thePlayer;

public:
POINT Position;
POINT relatPosition;

void update();
};
```

## map.cpp

```
Map::Map()
{
Position.x = 0;
Position.y = 0;
}

void Map::update()
{
relatMovement = *(thePlayer->getRelatMovement());
relatPosition.x -= relatMovement[0];
relatPosition.y -= relatMovement[1];
}
```

## Engine.h

```
class Engine
{
private:
Player thePlayer;
Map theMap;
Monster* allMonsters;

    int mapXstart=0, mapYstart=0, ammoNumberStart=0, enemiesNumberStart=0;

void input();
void update(float timeInSeconds);
void draw();

void setWindowSize(int mapX, int mapY);
void setMapSize(float mapWidth, float mapHeight);

public:
void start();
};
```

## Engine.cpp

```
Engine::Engine()
{
//setting map sprites
a = ((mapY+windowY) / theMap.mSprite.getTexture()->getSize().y) + 1;
b = ((mapX+windowX) / theMap.mSprite.getTexture()->getSize().x) + 1;
mapSprites = new sf::Sprite*[a];
for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    mapSprites[i] = new sf::Sprite[b];
    for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        mapSprites[i][j].setTexture(*theMap.mSprite.getTexture());
    }
}

//setting window
mWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(windowX, windowY), "CrimsonLikeGame", sf::Style::Default);

//setting game objects
//map
int mapRelX, mapRelY;
mapRelX = (windowX / 2) - (mapX / 2);
mapRelY = (windowY / 2) - (mapY / 2);

theMap.setRelativePosition(mapRelX, mapRelY);
theMap.setSize(mapX, mapY);
theMap.setPlayer(&thePlayer);

//player
thePlayer.setPosition(mapX/2,mapY/2);
thePlayer.setRelativePosition(windowX / 2, windowY / 2);
thePlayer.setMapSize(mapX, mapY);

//monsters
allMonsters = new Monster[enemiesNumber];

for (i = 0; i < enemiesNumber; i++) {
    allMonsters[i].setPlayer(&thePlayer);
    allMonsters[i].setMap(&theMap);
}
}   

void Engine::start()
{
sf::Clock clock;

//game loop
while (mWindow.isOpen()) {
    sf::Time dt = clock.restart();
    float dtAsSeconds = dt.asSeconds();

    input();
    update(dtAsSeconds);
    draw();
}
}
```

## input.cpp

```
void Engine::input() {
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape)) {
    mWindow.close();
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
    thePlayer.moveLeft();
}
else {
    thePlayer.stopLeft();
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
    thePlayer.moveRight();
}
else {
    thePlayer.stopRight();
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
    thePlayer.moveUp();
}
else {
    thePlayer.stopUp();
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
    thePlayer.moveDown();
}
else {
    thePlayer.stopDown();
}

if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
    mouseButtonPressed = true;
}
else {
    mouseButtonPressed = false;
}
}
```

## update.cpp

```
void Engine::update(float timeInSeconds) {

if (thePlayer.isAlive()&&enemiesAlive) {

    thePlayer.update(timeInSeconds);
    theMap.update();

    //Writing down, where each monster is going to go by it's next step
    for (i = 0; i < enemiesNumber; i++) {
        if (allMonsters[i].isAlive()) {
            enemiesNextSteps[i] = allMonsters[i].checkUpdate(timeInSeconds);
        }
    }

    //cheking - does anybody is going to collide
    for (i = 0; i < enemiesNumber; i++) {
        if (allMonsters[i].isAlive()) {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < enemiesNumber; j++) {
                if (j == i)
                    continue;
                else {
                    if ((((allMonsters[i].shape.left <= allMonsters[j].shape.right) && (allMonsters[i].shape.left >= allMonsters[j].shape.left)) || ((allMonsters[i].shape.right <= allMonsters[j].shape.right) && (allMonsters[i].shape.right >= allMonsters[j].shape.left))) && (((allMonsters[i].shape.bottom >= allMonsters[j].shape.top) && (allMonsters[i].shape.bottom <= allMonsters[j].shape.bottom)) || ((allMonsters[i].shape.top >= allMonsters[j].shape.top) && (allMonsters[i].shape.top <= allMonsters[j].shape.bottom)))) {
                        monstersCollide[i] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //updating each alive monster position without collisions
    for (i = 0; i < enemiesNumber; i++) {
        if (allMonsters[i].isAlive()/*&&!monstersCollide[i]*/) {
            allMonsters[i].setPosition(enemiesNextSteps[i]);
            allMonsters[i].update(timeInSeconds, enemiesNextSteps[i]);
        }
    }
}
else {                                       
//if player is dead - restart the game
    thePlayer.setAlive(true);
    for (i = 0; i < enemiesNumber; i++) {
        allMonsters[i].setAlive(true);
    }
}
}
```

I was trying to figure it out half a day. Hope you can help me with that problem.

Comment: During this half day have you placed a debugger breakpoint in `input` to follow the flow of the code through to see if `if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))` completes as expected?

Comment: Where are the brackets that one would expect to see with `void Player::moveLeft()
leftPressed = true;`

Comment: Suggestion: Back up your code and remove everything that isn't essential to the player walking around. Less code leaves fewer places for bugs to hide. It's also the first step to crafting the [mcve] required to accompany all "Why doesn't my code work?" problems.

Comment: How the struct POINT was declared?

Comment: POINT is a part of <Windows.h> header. I didn't mention it's inclusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I've actually built and ran this code, and the root cause for your movement problem is using integers for your coordinates, and ensuing assymetry:

```
if (rightPressed) 
    Position.x += speed * elapsedTime;

if (leftPressed)
    Position.x -= speed * elapsedTime;
```

Those two seem pretty equal at first, but when you consider what really happens, they differ slightly. Because your speed is relatively low (`1.0`), and so is your elapsed time (e.g. `~0.016` for one frame), the differences end up being less by one. To understand what happens next, you need to look at type conversions.

The statements are actually equivalent to:

```
Position.x = Position.x + (speed * elapsedTime);
```

Because `speed` and `elapsedTime` are floating point numbers, `Position.x` gets promoted to a float as well. Then the fraction is either added and subtracted, and *then* the result is converted back to an integer.

In case of moving left, the number e.g. `100` is converted to `100.0`, then `0.016` gets subtracted, resulting in `99.984`. Then, integer conversion removes the decimal part, resulting in the value of `99` and an observable change in your player's position.

In the case of moving right, we do the same, but we end up with a value of `100.016` instead. This converted back to integer results with a value of `100` again.

---

To fix this, the easiest solution is to make the player's position use floats as well. Then the small changes will be properly accumulated. You might observe that the player moves way slower than you'd expect at first, because the integer clamping effect will dissappear; setting the speed to `60` should get you more or less back where it was.

Comment: Also you might be interested in how I diagnosed this. I simply used a debugger, and first confirmed that the boolean flags get set properly. Then, I stepped through both cases and observed that while the `if` branch gets correctly executed, the value of `Position` variable didn't change. The I observed the values of `speed` and `elapsedTime`, and realized the difference was less than 1.0. Then it was just a matter of "go to definition" to find the type of `Position` and its members, and a bit of head-scratching :) - all in all it took about 10 minutes, build included.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working! 
I supposed, that it might be something about floats and integers, but didn't get what to do with them precisly. Yeah, it's so much for me to learn yet. Including using debagger details. Thanks one more time for such detailed response!